# keyboard layout changes automatically when i click on text in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, layout, keyboard

i have this problem when i'm in windows.i have two layout language that i use both of them on my works.the problem is when i'm in eclipse and type something with second layout language (my native language) then i want to put some html tag but when i click on that text my layout language in windows change automatically to that language.is there any way to disable this behavior?i want the keyboard layout changes when i press shortcut or with mouse click not automatically by click on text (written on that language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed my workspace to Netbeans and this problem doesn't existing there also it has all feature  of Zend studio such as refactor methods or parameters all over project , find usage and else and i think it is very powerful than eclipse and zend studio with no charge